# how to get alldirectories and sub directories those lastwrite time <= mydate LINQ c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-xml

i have following code how to add condition greater then less then and greater then lastwritetime >= mydatetime && laswritetime <= mylastdatetime and then find mynumber in xmlfile  how do this.

```
  var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)                            

                        from Findnumber in File.ReadAllLines(file)
                        where Findnumber.Contains(03895822323") 
                        select new
                        {                               
                            Findnumber = Findnumber,

                        };
```

Comment: `.Contains()` returns a boolean. You can't do `>=` on two bool values.

Comment: how to find number ?

Comment: You can use `long.Parse(FindNumber)>89889888889`

Comment: everyone dislike my post no one answer ;( properly

Comment: Let me know if `long.Parse(FindNumber)>89889888889` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @RezaAghaei i have condition and then find my number those file are belong to these dates..

Comment: Didn't you said numbers in the question? The logic for date is also the same.

Comment: i want get number in those dates

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(finddate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)>...`

Comment: Dear thanks for your answer but i want add condition then find mynumber  startdate  >= enddate

Comment: See the answer, It shows how you compare Date also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform `DateTime` comparison for `finddate`, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert the string to `DateTime` and then compare.

For example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(finddate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  <= DateTime.now
```

As another example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(finddate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  <= DateTime.ParseExact("2013-01-25 14:03:25", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: The answer is OK, anyway I added another example for you :)

Comment: Thanks :) Dear hope will you answer my question

Comment: Let me know if yo have any question about the answer.